# Gods dying and the legends rule

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-legendary-cards

So this came up in a game I was playing today. I had an [Athreos, God of Passage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Athreos%2C%20God%20of%20Passage) with enough devotion that it was a creature, and I cast another (it makes sense, I swear). I chose to sacrifice the newcomer.

This will trigger the remaining Athreos and I will return the dead god to my hand unless my opponent pays three, correct? Athreos was a creature when it died, and remained so after because its type-setting ability only applies on the battlefield.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the ability of the God that remains on the battlefield will trigger. When you play the second copy of Athreos, you will control 2 of them. Then, when state based effects are checked, by rule [704.5k](http://wiki.mtgsalvation.com/article/State-based_actions), you have to choose one to keep and move the other to the graveyard. This triggers the ability of the one still on the battlefield.

Comment: Technically, the other Athreos is just moved to the graveyard, not sacrificed, and so (for example) [Savra, Queen of the Golgari](http://magiccards.info/rav/en/225.html) won't trigger.

Comment: Rule 704.5k says, the duplicate is put into the owner's graveyard.  Is that the same as dying?  ...  I guess it is from rule 700.4, which says "The term dies means “is put into a graveyard from the battlefield.”"

Comment: Yes. It would die. It is not sacrificed, but the Athreos does die.